# Zoomable network graph in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, graph, d3.js, sigma.js

I would like to visualize a network graph in an AngularJS application. The nodes and edges are stored as a JSON object, and nodes will be added and modified later on (say once every 30 seconds). I want to use Angular data binding to automatically update the graph when the JSON object changes. The graph will have 10-1000 nodes. The nodes will be rectangular text nodes containing about a sentence each. I would like the graph to be zoom- and pan-able.

I know about the following options so far:

- [ArborJS](http://arborjs.org/)

  It is easy to make dynamic updating work with Angular (using `ParticleSystem.merge`). However, Arbor does not seem to support zoomable behavior, and it does not seem to be well-supported. For example, the [single-node bug](https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor/pull/29) is still unresolved.
- [D3](http://d3js.org/)

  There is [a zoomable force layout demo](http://bl.ocks.org/benzguo/4370043), and various places have information on using d3 with Angular. D3 is well-supported, but it seems lower-level than the options below. For example, creating [a network graph with good-looking rectangular node labels](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/Q5H8CuLpm1k) seems nontrivial.
- [VisJS](http://visjs.org/)

  VisJS supports zoomable network graphs, and there is [a work-in-progress Angular library](https://github.com/visjs/angular-visjs), but I don't know how reliable both VisJS and its Angular library are.
- [SigmaJS](http://sigmajs.org/)

  SigmaJS also supports zoomable network graphs, but I don't know whether it plays nicely with Angular.
- [CytoscapeJS](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/)
- [kmap](https://github.com/cjrd/kmap)

Are there other relevant libraries? What is the best library to use for this project, and how can I implement such a zoomable dynamic network graph given the library?

Comment: I'm not extremely familiar with each and every one of the ones listed on it, but the github 'Explore' page has a visualization section that you might want to check out. https://github.com/showcases/data-visualization

Comment: Repost this post in the software recommendation stackexchange instead: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Awesome thread, this !! Thanks @Andreas , I had some ideas now with some of the libraries here makes it easier to choose. Good recommendations !!

Answer (score 19):

I've been experimenting in [VisJs](https://visjs.org/) in angular, and I'm really liking it so far. Their network is both pannable and zoomable, and you can select nodes. The documentation has been easy to follow and there are a lot of examples on their site.
Since vis's networks can dynamically update, I found it easy to integrate it in my angular app. For example, I created this directive:

```
app.directive('visNetwork', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            onSelect: '&',
            options: '='
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel) {
            var network = new vis.Network($element[0], $scope.ngModel, $scope.options || {});

            var onSelect = $scope.onSelect() || function(prop) {};
            network.on('select', function(properties) {
                onSelect(properties);
            });

        }

    }
});
```

Which I use in my html like so:

```
<vis-network ng-model="network_data" options="network_options" on-select="onNodeSelect" id="previewNetwork">
</vis-network>
```

Then in my controller I have the following:

```
    $scope.nodes = new vis.DataSet();
    $scope.edges = new vis.DataSet();
    $scope.network_data = {
        nodes: $scope.nodes,
        edges: $scope.edges
    };
    $scope.network_options = {
        hierarchicalLayout: {
            direction: "UD"
        }

    };

   $scope.onNodeSelect = function(properties) {
        var selected = $scope.task_nodes.get(properties.nodes[0]);
        console.log(selected);
    };

    $scope.nodes.add([
        {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
        {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
        {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
        {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
        {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}]);

    $scope.edges.add([
        {id: 1, from: 1, to: 2},
        {id: 2, from: 3, to: 2}
    ]);
```

Answer (score 12):

This should really be on [Software Recommendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange but I can't vote to close because of the bounty.

[GoJS](http://www.gojs.net/latest/index.html) supports all of your requirements and works alongside Angular ([simple demo here](http://www.gojs.net/latest/samples/angular.html)). (JSON for Model storage, data-binding, zoom and pan built in)

Comment: I [reposted on the software recs stackexchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7339/zoomable-network-graph-in-angularjs). If an answer is accepted there, I'd be happy for the author to post a link to their answer here and I will award the bounty.

Comment: GoJS looks great. The fact that it is not a *free* open-source library is a major drawback, though.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good demo/example of a network map with sourcecode in D3: http://christophergandrud.github.io/d3Network/
The functionality is all there, and D3 seems to play nice with JSON. From my research, this is a strong choice for a visualization library. Many other libraries (graphite, etc.) also support the same functionality but are harder to implement and aren't extremely active.

NVD3 is a variation of D3 designed for AngularJS that could also work. Implementing graphs and charts from within NVD3 is easier in AngularJS than D3 would be.

Comment: One reason I am hesitant to use D3 is that I haven't seen any examples that use rectangular nodes with longer labels (requiring wrapping). Almost all examples I have seen tend to use circular nodes, and people seem to have had trouble creating graphs with good-looking rectangular nodes in the past (see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/Q5H8CuLpm1k)).

Comment: + d3Network look like command line tool :( 
Can we use in JS application?

Answer (score 0):

In a commercial context you should also consider [yFiles for HTML](https://www.yworks.com/yfileshtml) as a library for bringing high-quality [graph visualization to Angular](https://www.yworks.com/pages/angular-diagram-component) (and AngularJS) powered-apps.

It's a full-featured graph drawing and editing software library that provides solutions for all your graphing and diagramming needs.

Specifically 1000 nodes are not a problem, at least if this is not on low-end, older mobile devices, in which case only simple visualizations will provide good performance. But even then, with the unique hybrid rendering engine that can leverage all of SVG, Canvas, and WebGL at the same time in a diagram even that should work.

For a thousand nodes with each one line of text on them, on low-end devices it will be problematic to display all of them on the screen at the same time, however virtualization also helps here.

There are some [live, online demos](https://live.yworks.com/demos/#angular) that show different levels of Angular(2+) and AngularJS integrations, but if you really want to play with the library on a programming level, you should download it and check out the non-minified sources for those demos. For Angular2+ development a complete set of TypeScript bindings is available and the samples show how to bind angular-data to the graph visualization as well as how to optionally use angular for the templating of the SVG visualizations. Of course they also include the core graph visualization Angular component.

<sup>Disclosure: I work for the company that provides that library, however I do not represent my employer on SO.</sup>