# AngularJS Friendly Library for node edge diagrams (with layout)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, graph, diagram, gojs

I'm looking for a JS library that can render interactive node edge diagrams.
Ideally it should integrate well with AngularJS, but I can always create a wrapper for one if it doesn't exist.

Ideally I'd use: http://gojs.net/, but the cost is prohibitively high.

Does anyone have any recommendations for an alternative?

Comment: Contact gosales@nwoods.com to see if you qualify for some kind of discount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are few in markets like

1. http://arborjs.org/
2. http://visjs.org/
3. http://sigmajs.org/
4. https://github.com/cjrd/kmap

There is a similar discussion here
[Zoomable network graph in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24396708/zoomable-network-graph-in-angularjs)

Comment: VisJS looks good, will check it out.